# Passing value from ListView to another Activity/Class

Tags: java, android, listview

So here I have class ListProductActivity.java that display list of products based on the search criteria entered by user and the data are retrieve from MySQL server using Json. My question is, how can I pass a single value (productName in this case) when user select from the listview to another activity so that I can use that value in the new Activity (viewProductActivity.java).

ListProductActivity.java

```
public class ListProductActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView list;
    private ProgressDialog loading;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_product);
        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
        getData();
    }
    public void getData(){

        String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("productName");

        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Please wait...","Fetching...",false,false);

        String url = Config.DATA_URL2 + s;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showList(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(ListProductActivity.this,error.getMessage().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }

    private void showList(String response){

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray products = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

            for(int i=0;i<products.length();i++){
                JSONObject productData = products.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = productData.getString(KEY_NAME);
                String price = productData.getString(KEY_PRICE);
                String brand = productData.getString(KEY_BRAND);

                HashMap<String,String> product = new HashMap<String,String>();

                product.put(KEY_NAME,name);
                product.put(KEY_PRICE,price);
                product.put(KEY_BRAND,brand);

                productList.add(product);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    ListProductActivity.this, productList, R.layout.list_product,

                    new String[]{KEY_NAME,KEY_PRICE,KEY_BRAND},
                    new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.price, R.id.brand}
            );

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

So, what function can I implement in my ListProductActivity class to pass the productName based on user selected in the listView to another activity and how to receive the passing value in viewProductActivity class?

I really hope you guys can post the function and briefly explain on how it works, so that I can understand the codes really well. Comment at the codes will be more clear and helpful. Thank You.

Edited

Here is the picture of the result from the listview after searching
[Click To View Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MZSy.png)

Comment: Did you try passing it through intent in your listview adapter

Comment: @AliAsheer I don't know how. Perhaps u can show me how to do?

Comment: post the adapter code including the part where you go to the new Activity

Comment: You can set `setOnItemSelectlistner` on your `listView` and get the value of selected item and pass it with the intent

Comment: @KenZo Miyazaw you can find the answer in the post that Murat K. posted the link

Comment: @pankajkhedekar can u post the full function for that?

Comment: see answer of Exigente05 or krupa  for that. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First simply implement onItemClickListener of listview on current activity

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String product_name = productList.get(position).get(KEY_NAME); 
                Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,YourNextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("product_name",product_name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

and receive that value in onCreate method of YourNextActivity.java like this:

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String productname = bundle.getString("product_name");
```

Comment: based on my class above, where should I put this codes?

Comment: Write setOnItemClickListener in your ListProductActivity.java and receive that value in viewProductActivity.java

Comment: Thank you.. it's working.. I accepted your answer as the most relevant to my question..

Comment: Happy coding :)

Answer (score 3):

Implement like this,

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
   @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
      String name = productList.get(position).get(KEY_NAME);
      Intent i;
        i = new Intent(mContext, viewProductActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("productName",name);
        startActivity(i);
  } 
});
```

Comment: based on my class above, where should I put this codes?

Comment: put inside onCreate() above getData();

Answer (score 2):

Pass the array list to the new activity later you can use whatever you want from that extra
eg:-

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx, SecondActivity.class);

            i.putExtra("List", List); //List is an arraylist like yours

            startActivity(i);
```

Second activity:

```
SList = (ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("List");
```

Now use whatever you want using SList.get(0).get("keyname")

Answer (score 2):

put your code here

```
private void showList(String response){

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray products = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);

            for(int i=0;i<products.length();i++){
                JSONObject productData = products.getJSONObject(i);
                String name = productData.getString(KEY_NAME);
                String price = productData.getString(KEY_PRICE);
                String brand = productData.getString(KEY_BRAND);

                HashMap<String,String> product = new HashMap<String,String>();

                product.put(KEY_NAME,name);
                product.put(KEY_PRICE,price);
                product.put(KEY_BRAND,brand);

                productList.add(product);
            }

            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                    ListProductActivity.this, productList, R.layout.list_product,

                    new String[]{KEY_NAME,KEY_PRICE,KEY_BRAND},
                    new int[]{R.id.name, R.id.price, R.id.brand}
            );

            list.setAdapter(adapter);

           // put your new code here
           list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                String product_name = productList.get(position).get(KEY_NAME); 
                Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this,YourNextActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("product_name",product_name);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Thank You.. Your answer really helpful to my question..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it via Intent in your listview adapter as

```
        Intent i;
        i = new Intent(mContext, viewProductActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("productName",whateverstring);
        mContext.startActivity(i);
```

Comment: need to put the code inside itemSelectListner .

Comment: then put this same code just replace `mContext` with `ListProductActivity.this`